# prove $(n)$ prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n$ is prime or zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

prove $(n)$  prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n$ is prime or zero

---

**Defintions**

Def of prime Ideal (n)
$$ ab\in (n) \implies a\in(n) \vee b\in(n) $$
Def 1]  integer n is prime if $n \neq 0,\pm 1 $ and only divisors are $\pm n,\pm 1$

Def 2 of n is prime] If $n\neq0,\pm1$  only divisors of n are $\pm1,\pm n$
$$ n|ab \implies n|a \vee n|b $$

---

$\Rightarrow $] (*Prime Ideal $(n)$ of $\mathbb{Z} $$\Rightarrow$ $n$ prime or zero*)

Now consider the case where $(n)\neq (0)$. that is $n\neq 0$

Using the def of prime Ideals $$\begin{aligned} ab \in (n) \implies a \in(n) \vee b \in (n) \end{aligned}  $$

Well, If an element $x\in(n) \iff x=q*n \iff n|x$

$$n|ab \implies n|a \vee n|b$$
 So, $n$ is prime ,nonzero.

In the case that $(n)=(0)$ clearly $n=0$ since there are no zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}$

$\Leftarrow$] *(n is prime or zero  $\Rightarrow $ $(n)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$)*

Consider the case where $p is prime$ so $n\neq 0, \pm1$

$$ \begin{aligned} 
n|ab &\implies n|a \vee n|b \\
ab \in (n) &\implies a \in (n) \vee b\in(n) \end{aligned}$$

in the case $n=0$, since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no zero divisors 
$$ab=0 \implies a=0 \vee b=0 $$
So (0) is a prime ideal.

---

Concern if this prove holds, also would be surprised if this question is not out there in this site. Did a search and clicked on similar questions and could not find it.And of course any other ways to prove it.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ is a field if $n$ is prime?

Comment: $Z/(n)$ is a field iff $(n)$ is a maximal. So every maximal is a prime that is $(n)$ is prime. Thanks @SirJective :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain or that it has unique factorization. Don't you also need the definition that a prime ideal has to be properly contained within the whole ring?

If $n = \pm 1$, then $\langle n \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$ and thus it can't be a prime ideal. If $n$ is composite and divisible by some prime $p$, then $\langle n \rangle$ is properly contained within $\langle p \rangle$ and thus $\langle n \rangle$ is not a prime ideal either.

And then you just proceed with what you have already demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from $p \mid a \iff a \in (p)$ we have more generally in a commutative ring with unity, $(p)$ is a prime ideal iff $p$ is prime (in the ring theory sense: $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a \vee p \mid b$)